# PostgreSQL: 'ON CONFLICT' with constraint name

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's a SQL query for PostgreSQL DB.

```
INSERT INTO table1(user_id, product, val3)
VALUES(1, 1, 'some_value')
ON CONFLICT (user_id, product)
DO UPDATE SET val3 = ""
```

For table with constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT con1 UNIQUE (user_id, product);
```

Is any way to write ON CONFLICT in query without (user_id, product), but with using the name of this constraint (con1)?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html <<--  *conflict_target*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes:

```
INSERT INTO table1(user_id, product, val3)
VALUES(1, 1, 'some_value')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT con1
DO UPDATE SET val3 = '';
```

Comment: Yes, that works, it avoids specifying the columns which cause the duplication. You type less. But in return it is harder to see what is the cause. I now have to look up the definition of `con1` to see what the issue is, after all there are 7 possible definitions for it. (IMHO) Seems like a giant step backwards.